# Configuring IP and network address for Windows Mobile Hotspot

Tags: windows, networking, wifi

I'm using Windows Mobile Hotspot on my laptop to share its Internet connection with other devices.

It sets up a DHCP service, using 192.168.137.1 as the gateway address, and leasing out addresses on 192.168.137.xxx network.

How can I change these settings? Suppose I want my gateway address to be 192.168.13.37, and the users of the Mobile Hotspot to be assigned 192.168.13.xxx addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not really configurable.
The use of mobile hotspot is only for sharing your internet connection.

However, it seems that there is a workaround described in [in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/804227/how-to-get-assigned-ips-by-hostednetwork/940050#940050).

This is for configuring an static IP and then use a different DHCP service